# Edit every Nth item in a list

Tags: list, haskell

I want to perform an arithmetic operation (e.g. doubling the value) on a list of integers, every n places.

For example, given the list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, I want to double values every three places. In that case, we would have `[1,2,6,4,5,12,7]`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A common way to get indexes for values in a list is to `zip` the list into tuples of `(value, index)`.

```
ghci > let zipped = zip [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] [1..]
ghci > zipped
[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7)]
```

Then you just need to `map` over that list and return a new one. If index is divisible by 3 (`` index `rem` 3 == 0 ``), we'll double the value, otherwise we'll return the same value:

```
ghci > map (\(value, index) -> if index `rem` 3 == 0 then value*2 else value) zipped
[1,2,6,4,5,12,7]
```

Tell me if that all makes sense—I can add more detail if you aren't familiar with `zip` and `map` and such.

#### Zip

You can find documentation on `zip` by looking at its [Haddocks](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.5/base-4.8.2.0/Prelude.html#v:zip), which say: "zip takes two lists and returns a list of corresponding pairs." (Docs are hosted in several places, but I went to https://www.stackage.org and searched for `zip`).

#### Map

The [`map`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.5/base-4.8.2.0/Prelude.html#v:map) function applies a function to each item in a list, generating a new value for each element.

#### Lambdas

Lambdas are just functions without a specific name. We used one in the first argument to `map` to say what we should do to each element in the list. You may have seen these in other languages like Python, Ruby, or Swift.

This is the syntax for lambdas:

```
(\arg1, arg2 -> functionBodyHere)
```

We could have also written it without a lambda:

```
ghci > let myCalculation (value, index) = if index `rem` 3 == 0 then value*2 else value
ghci > map myCalculation zipped
[1,2,6,4,5,12,7]
```

Comment: Yes please, if you want, add more details. I'm an absolute newcomer of haskell. Thanks!

Comment: I think yatima's answer is more elegant, If I may say so. But yours is theaching me more, as it would do to any absolute beginner. I'll accept yours.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about lambdas, very very useful.
Let me ask you just one more question: Why you wrote `let mycalculation` instead of defining a proper function with type declaration, etc cetera?

Comment: @MadHatter I was writing the function in GHCi, and in you need to define functions with `let` before them (Code you run in GHCi is like code you add to your `main` function, not like a top-level definition of a function). If I was writing the code in a file I would have had a type declaration and such.

Answer (score 13):

```
applyEvery :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
applyEvery n f = zipWith ($) (cycle (replicate (n-1) id ++ [f]))
```

The `cycle` subexpression builds a list of functions `[id,id,...,id,f]` with the correct number of elements and repeats it ad nauseam, while the `zipWith ($)` applies that list of functions to the argument list.

---

Since you asked for it, more detail! Feel free to ask for more explanation.

The main idea is maybe best explained with an ASCII picture (which won't stop me from writing <strike>a thousand</strike> a lot of ASCII words!):

```
functions : [ id, id, f  , id, id, f  , id, id, f, ... 
input list: [  1,  2,   3,  4,  5,   6,  7 ]
-----------------------------------------------------
result    : [  1,  2, f 3,  4,  5, f 6,  7 ]
```

Just like there's no reason to hardcode the fact that you want to double every third element in the list, there's nothing special about `f` (which in your example is doubling), except that it should have the same result type as doing nothing. So I made these the parameters of my function. It's even not important that you operate on a list of numbers, so the function works on lists of `a`, as long as it's given an 'interval' and an operation. That gives us the type signature `applyEvery :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]`. I put the input list last, because then a partial application like `doubleEveryThird = applyEvery 3 (*2)` is something that returns a new list, a so-called *combinator*. I picked the order of the other two arguments basically at random :-)

To build the list of functions, we first assemble the basic building block, consisting of n-1 `id`s, followed by an `f` as follows: `replicate (n-1) id ++ [f]`. `replicate m x` makes a list containing `m` repetitions of the `x`argument, e.g. `replicate 5 'a' = "aaaaa"`, but it also works for functions. We have to append the `f` wrapped in a list of its own, instead of using `:` because you can only prepend single elements at the front - Haskell's lists are singly-linked.

Next, we keep on repeating the basic building block with `cycle` (not `repeat` as I first had mistakenly). `cycle` has type `[a] -> [a]` so the result is a list of "the same level of nested-ness". Example `cycle [1,2,3]` evaluates to `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,...]`

[ Side note: the only repeat-y function we *haven't* used is `repeat` itself: that forms an infinite list consisting of its argument ]

With that out of the way, the slightly tricky `zipWith ($)` part. You might already know the plain `zip` function, which takes two lists and puts elements in the same place in a tuple in the result, terminating when either list runs out of elements. Pictorially:

```
    xs   : [ a  , b    , c   , d, e] 
       ys: [   x,    y ,   z ]
------------------------------
zip xs ys: [(a,x),(b,y),(c,z)]
```

This already looks an awful lot like the first picture, right? The only thing is that we don't want to put the individual elements together in a tuple, but apply the first element (which is a function) to the second instead. Zipping with a custom combining function is done with `zipWith`. Another picture (the last one, I promise!):

```
          xs   : [   a  ,   b  ,   c   , d, e] 
             ys: [     x,     y,     z ]
----------------------------------------
zipWith f xs ys: [ f a x, f b y, f c z ]
```

Now, what should we choose to `zipWith` with? Well, we want to apply the first argument to the second, so `(\f x -> f x)` should do the trick. If lambdas make you uncomfortable, you can also define a top-level function `apply f x = f x` and use that instead. However, this already a standard operator in the Prelude, namely `$`! Since you can't use a infix operator as a standalone function, we have to use the syntactic sugar `($)` (which really just means `(\f x -> f $ x)`)

Putting all of the above together, we get:

```
applyEvery :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
applyEvery n f xs = zipWith ($) (cycle (replicate (n-1) id ++ [f])) xs
```

But we can get rid of the `xs` at the end, leading to the definition I gave.

Comment: May I ask what `($)` stands for? I thought that `$` would be useful just to get rid of parentheses..

Comment: Btw, your answer is very elegant and "haskelish".. I'm accepting Gabriel's just because is perhaps more suited for an absolute beginner like me.
But, If you want, you can explain yours step by step, in further advantage of any beginner that should catch this post.

Comment: @MadHatter `f $ x = f x` - that is, `$` takes a function and a value, and calls the function with the value. It's often used in place of parentheses because `$` has a very low precedence when used as an infix operator. But it can be used as an ordinary function, as here, and in that case it's the same as writing `zipWith (\f x -> f x) (...)`.

Comment: Isn't it cleaner to write `tail . cycle $ f : replicate (n-1) id`, instead of `cycle ((replicate (n-1) id) ++ [f])`? You avoid having to use `(++ [x])` to add to the end of a list, which is a good thing to avoid.

Comment: @amalloy: Yeah, that's actually better! It both looks nicer and is a bit more efficient. `concat . intersperse f $ replicate (n-1) id` would also do the trick, now that I think of it, but that needs `Data.List`.

Comment: Definitely great explanation! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `xs ++ ys` takes time proportional to the number of elements in xs to fully evaluate, so you have to pay attention to not let your algorithm runtime become quadratic if there's a better way. In this case it's not going to hurt for smallish values of `n` though, but seeing `++[x]` should trigger you to look for an alternate solution.

Comment: I know one should not use comments just to say thanks, but in this case I feel compelled to thank you all for all those instructive explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Note: this code is not yet tested.

In `lens` land, this is called a `Traversal`. `Control.Lens` gives you these:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

type Traversal s t a b =
  forall f . Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t

type Traversal' s a = Traversal s s a a
```

We can use `lens`'s `itraverse` from `Control.Lens.Indexed`:

```
-- everyNth :: (TraversableWithIndex i t, Integral i)
            => i -> Traversal' (t a) a
everyNth :: (TraversableWithIndex i t, Integral i, Applicative f)
         => i -> (a -> f a) -> t a -> f (t a)
everyNth n f = itraverse f where
  g i x | i `rem` n == n - 1 = f x
        | otherwise = pure x
```

This can be specialized to your specific purpose:

```
import Data.Profunctor.Unsafe
import Data.Functor.Identity

everyNthPureList :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
everyNthPureList n f = runIdentity #. everyNth n (Identity #. f)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mapIf :: (Int -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapIf pred f l = map (\(value,index) -> if (pred index) then f value else value) $ zip l [1..]

mapEveryN :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapEveryN n = mapIf (\x -> x `mod` n == 0)
```

[Live on Ideone](http://ideone.com/kSQwdE).

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive approach:

```
everyNth n f xs = igo n xs where
    igo 1 (y:ys) = f y : igo n     ys
    igo m (y:ys) =   y : igo (m-1) ys
    igo _ [] = []

doubleEveryThird = everyNth 3 (*2)
```

Basically, igo starts at `n`, counts down until it reaches `1`, where it will apply the function, and go back up to `n`. `doubleEveryThird` is partially applied: `everyNth` expects three arguments, but we only gave it two, so `dougleEveryThird` will expect that final argument.